# save a post request with fiddler script OnBeforeRequest event?

Tags: post, request, save, fiddler

For testing purpose 
i would use this code to pause a post request with customizerules.js file

static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session)
    {
if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("POST") && (oSession.utilFindInRequest("mykeyword", true) > -1)){
oSession["x-breakrequest"] = "keyword";

// i need to save the post request to file here

}
}

Is there anything

Comment: Is there a question there?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're asking. Your **x-breakrequest** Session flag suffices to set a request breakpoint for the specified request.

If you'd like to further save the request body to a file, you could do something like:

`File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\temp\\" + oSession.id.ToString() + " .txt",
                     oSession.requestBodyBytes);`

Keep in mind that this saves the *original* request body, not including any modifications the user may have made to the body while the request was paused at the breakpoint.

Comment: Hi Eric

Thanks for your answer, this was very helpful by the way.

But the problem is that, i would  edit the request which  i already   save to a file and  send it back to the server.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Why do you need to edit it in a file, instead of just using Fiddler's Inspectors to edit it?

Comment: I used the fiddler inspectors and it work fine  to edit the header before send it to the server, but  i want to try sending  a captured request with different sessions at the same time.

 this code work fine for me, the only thing is that i cannot save the http header 
'File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\temp\\" + oSession.id.ToString() + " .txt",
                     oSession.requestBodyBytes);'

**requestBodyBytes** can save only the body.